# Time measurement via sleep () or usleep ()

Tags: linux, macos, c++11, timer, sleep

I try to measure an exact time and have tried ... but with a "sleep (1) / usleep (1000)" I do not get what I expect.

Here my test code and the result:

```
unsigned long long start;
unsigned long long end;

// Example A:

start = mach_absolute_time();
sleep(1);
end = mach_absolute_time();
printf( "\nA:----------\n\t%f seconds\n", mach_elapsed_time(start, end) / 1000000000.0 );

// Example B:

start = mach_absolute_time();
usleep(1000);
end = mach_absolute_time();
printf( "\nB:---1000---\n\t%f seconds\n", mach_elapsed_time(start, end) / 1000000.0);

// Example C:

start = mach_absolute_time();
usleep(900);
end = mach_absolute_time();
printf( "\nC:----900---\n\t%f seconds\n", mach_elapsed_time(start, end) / 1000000.0);

// Example D:

start = mach_absolute_time();
usleep(815);
end = mach_absolute_time();
printf( "\nD:----815---\n\t%f seconds\n", mach_elapsed_time(start, end) / 1000000.0);
```

I get this output:

```
A:----------
    1.000097 seconds    // Almost what I expect
B:---1000---
    1.252341 seconds
C:----900---
    1.127429 seconds
D:----815---
    1.021522 seconds
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Is it intentional that your first example divides by a billion whereas the rest divide by only a million?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking why that is occurring? The [usleep man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) explains: "The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers."?

Comment: What exactly does `mach_elapsed_time` do?

Comment: @kaylum: I assume his/her question is why the duration of `usleep` seems to be so much more greater, proportionally, than that of `sleep`. But it's cheating, because despite what his/her output claims, (s)he's actually having `usleep` sleep for a much much shorter duration than (s)he's having `sleep` sleep for.

Comment: @ruakh Well, that's pretty obvious. If you ask someone to come back in as cose to a day as possible, they'll be off by less than 1%. If you ask them to come back in as close to a second as possible, it's not likely they'll be that accurate.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Don't tell me, tell the OP. :-)

Comment: Yes, I know that system activities count, but the deviations are too large (for me). Also I do not understand that with local variables more time is needed than with those from a class.

Comment: This is what I need is: after the time between 995..1005 ms an action must be triggered on the CAN bus. What is the better solution? I ask for a usleep (980); Until I reach a value close to 1000 ms ....